# How to remove ONE item if there are two items having the same value in array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6

So I have this array of objects of cards which I'm displaying in vuejs.

```js
cardsFromBackEnd: [
  {
    id: 1,
    tickerName: 'IBM',
    tickerFullName: 'International Business Machines',
    benchMark: 121.3,
    totalReturn: 16.9,
    tradeReturn: -14.0,
    sharpeRatio: 0.0006,
    winRate: 28.2,
    date: 'Mon Oct 31',
    tags: ['IBM'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tickerName: 'HP',
    tickerFullName: 'Hawlett-Packard',
    benchMark: 91.3,
    totalReturn: 10.9,
    tradeReturn: 23.2,
    sharpeRatio: 0.0006,
    winRate: 68.2,
    date: 'Sun Oct 30',
    tags: ['IBM'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tickerName: 'Appl',
    tickerFullName: 'Apple',
    benchMark: 201.3,
    totalReturn: 110.9,
    tradeReturn: 173.2,
    sharpeRatio: 0.0006,
    winRate: 168.2,
    date: 'Sat Oct 29',
    tags: [],
  },
],
```

I'm showing tags on the bottom left corner which are saved in `tags` array.

the tags also have a remove button. when there are different tags in cards, only that tag is deleted which is clicked. But my issue is that if there is a tag which has the same value in both cards get clicked for removal, that tag is removed from both cards.

here is the html of tags

```
<vs-chip
  v-for="tag in cardData.tags"
  :key="tag.id"
  @click="remove(tag)"
  closable
  close-icon="delete"
  >
  {{ tag }}
</vs-chip>
```

and here is the click event

```js
remove(tag) {
  eventBus.$emit('delTag', tag);
},
```

and here is the listener for that remove method

```js
// Deleting tag on clicked card
eventBus.$on('delTag', (tag) => {
    let cardTags = this.cardDetails.filter((card) => {
    if (card.tags.includes(tag)) {
      card.tags.splice(card.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a way to tell that only delete that tag from the card on which it was clicked for removal?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're clicking on a particular card's tags, can you not just alter that card's tags, eg `card.tags = card.tags.filter(tag => tag !== tagToRemove)`? Without seeing your template or methods, this is difficult to answer

Comment: Use a loop that you can `break` out of, instead. That would be a simple fix, to what is probably a larger problem. If your cards were dynamically created then why did you not add the Events to the specific Elements at the time? Maybe you used `.innerHTML` to create your Elements. I recommend `document.createElement` instead. Once assigned to a variable, just assign Events.

Comment: Also, you're definitely not using `Array.prototype.filter()` correctly

Comment: @StackSlave the question is tagged with [tag:vue.js] so `document.createElement()` and `innerHTML` are not good options

Comment: @Phil What is the correct way to use ```Array.prototype.filter()```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the id of the clicked card to your function and do something like this, and you don't need to use filter in your case.

```
let cardTags = getCardTags(theOnClickedCardId)

function getCardTags(theOnClickedCardId){
return this.cardDetails.map((card) => {
   if (card.tags.includes(tag) && card.id == theOnClickedCardId) {
     card.tags.splice(card.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
   }
})};
```

Comment: first of all thank you for answering to my question. So I've tried this but now it's not removing the tag. Any other suggestions you have? Also I've updated the question so you can understand more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Pass both the card and tag to your `remove()` method and event

```html
<vs-chip
  v-for="tag in cardData.tags"
  :key="tag.id"
  @click="remove(cardData, tag)"
  closable
  close-icon="delete"
  >
  {{ tag }}
</vs-chip>
```

```js
remove(card, tag) {
  eventBus.$emit('delTag', { card, tag })
},
```

```js
eventBus.$on('delTag', ({ card, tag }) => {
  card.tags = card.tags.filter(cardTag => cardTag !== tag)

  // or

  card.tags.splice(card.tags.indexOf(tag), 1)
})
```

Comment: There are two components. one is the card component and the other is the component on which the card renders and the data of cards come from backend from the that component. And the data is passed through props to the card component.

Comment: @WaleedAliKhan _ok_? Is the `cardData` in the first component somehow detached from the primary card data?

Comment: so the ```cardData``` is a prop and is typeof object. So what I'm doing is looping over ```cardsFromBackEnd``` in the parent component and sending objects through prop to the child(card) component.

Comment: @WaleedAliKhan I'm not sure what this all has to do with my answer